# Why are events not working after changing innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two buttons on my site, you click on one, one gallery appears, on the other you click - another. This is javascript in php file in wordpress and php loop in javascript. I have used various image gallery scripts - for example bootstrap 5, magnific-popup.js.

This all works fine normally, but if I insert this gallery via javascript innerHtml, the popup doesn't work. The gallery itself appears, but does not work. When you click on the image, it just opens on a black screen and that's it. How to make images pop up in a modal window and everything would work?

```
jQuery(".nd-doc-btn").click(function() {
  const docsList = document.getElementById("nd-docs");
  docsList.style.opacity = 0;
  if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('nd-clicked-doc')) {
    jQuery(".nd-doc-btn").removeClass('nd-clicked-doc');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('nd-doc-btn-doc');
    jQuery(this).addClass('nd-clicked-doc');
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('nd-btn1')) {

      setTimeout(function() {

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          insertModal();
        });

        function insertModal() {

          let modal1 = '<div class="row gy-4 pb-5 justify-content-center nd-docs"><?php if( have_rows('
          gallery_loop ') ): while( have_rows('
          gallery_loop ') ) : the_row(); ?><div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 d-grid justify-content-center"><div class="magnific-img"><a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="<?php $img_gallery_loop = get_sub_field('
          img_gallery_loop '); echo esc_url($img_gallery_loop['
          url ']); ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery"><?php $img_data_caption = get_sub_field('
          img_data_caption ');  if( !empty( $img_gallery_loop ) ): ?> <img src="<?php echo esc_url($img_gallery_loop['
          url ']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($img_gallery_loop['
          alt ']); ?>" class="img-fluid" /><?php endif; ?></a></div><div class="nd-caption text-center"><p><?php echo $img_data_caption; ?></p></div></div><?php
          endwhile;
          endif; ? > < /div>';

          docsList.innerHTML = modal1;

          docsList.style.opacity = 1;
        }
      }, 700);
    }
  }
});

<div class="container">
  <div id="nd-docs"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: N.B. `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` is redundant in this scenario. If the code got this far, the page will have been ready long ago.

Comment: ADyson, in one post I just read that for this you need to reinitialize the function, probably not in this case.

Comment: That's nonsense. Either that or you misunderstood what was said, or took it out of context. `.ready()` is an event handler to stop the code within it from running before the whole page is loaded and ready. Therefore, there is no chance you will need it within a timeout which is already within a click handler! Read https://api.jquery.com/ready/ and http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: When you "insert the gallery via javascript" does it include `".nd-doc-btn"`?   Or is it the `lightbox` that's not working (in your `let modal1=`).  If it's the lightbox it's because it uses `data-toggle=` and essentially, the code with do `$(() => $("[data-toggle]").initLightbox())` - so adding a lightbox after the first init then won't be init'd (as you've found) - you need to init the lightbox after you insert your html.  How you do that depends on which lightbox plugin is used and its js code to initialise.

Comment: freedomn-m, Thanks a lot! I inserted the init code after the innerHtml is inserted and it worked. Inside setTimeout(function(){

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `innerHTML`, none of the items inside will work. I have created this example, where the first button will show you an alert until the second button is clicked:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("firstbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("Working");
    });
    document.getElementById("secondbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = `<input id="firstbtn" type="button" value="Click Me!">`;
        alert("From now on the other button will not work");
    });
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <input id="firstbtn" type="button" value="Click Me!">
</div>
<input id="secondbtn" type="button" value="Reset">
```

So, the solution is to separate your event handler additions into a re-executable code section, so, whenever the `innerHTML` changes, you can rerun the handler addition. See the example below where the first button works even though the second button changes the innerHTML of the container:

```js
function initContainer(container) {
    container.querySelector("#firstbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("Working");
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    initContainer(document.getElementById("container"));
    document.getElementById("secondbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = `<input id="firstbtn" type="button" value="Click Me!">`;
        initContainer(document.getElementById("container"));
        alert("The first button will work even though the inner HTML has changed!");
    });
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <input id="firstbtn" type="button" value="Click Me!">
</div>
<input id="secondbtn" type="button" value="Reset">
```